# Self-Intersection under Blow up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, blowup

Let $X$ be a algebraic surface,  $\Lambda$ be a linear system, and $p\in \Lambda$ be its base point. We blow up $X$ at $p$, denote the exceptional curve $E$.

**Q**: For any $C\in|\Lambda|$, can we say $(\sigma^*(C)-m_p(E))(\sigma^*(C)-m_p(E))\geq0$, where $\sigma$ denotes the blow up process, $m_p$ means the multiple number at $p$, and $E$ denotes the exceptional curve?

Comment: $\sigma^*(C)^2=C^2$.

Comment: @Mohan So sorry, I made a mistake, please see the modified question.

Comment: Bad notation. If you meant $m_p(C)E$, this is correct  for a general curve $C\in|\Lambda|$.